# Loop cut shortcut not working on Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I'm a newbie just getting into Blender and I'm following a tutorial that was filmed using 2.8 in beta. In the tutorial, the author is doing a [`Loop Cut`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and mouse wheel to change the *Number of Cuts* but it's not happening in my official 2.8 version of Blender. Has this changed when 2.8 came out of beta? Also, after he creates a number of cuts, he is able to move the cuts vertically on the Z-axis and I'm not able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment you write

> I was in edit mode and have selected the loop cut tool, the same tool you have there in the image.

That is exactly the problem. If you have the Loop Cut tool selected in the toolbar, choosing the number of cuts with the mouse wheel doesn't work and <kbd>LMB</kbd> does not allow you to slide.

Try selecting the Select Box tool (or any other tool really) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will work as shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same problem.

The solution is:

1. Click select box mode or click <kbd>W</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
3. Hover object and scroll!

Then you can use mouse wheel to change the number of cuts!

Don't use at 'loop cut' mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

make sure your in edit mode (press tab with the object you want to edit selected), and you need to have your mouse over the area you want to make the cut with. It hasn't changed when it came out of beta. There is also a button on the left side for this in edit mode, if you don't like using shortcuts. The image of it is below. And if for some reason you can't see that, press T to toggle the tool bar on and off.

[image]

Comment: I was in edit mode and have selected the loop cut tool, the same tool you have there in the image. Is CTRL + R the right hotkey for this?

Comment: Figured it out, I had to select "Edge Select" to get the option to increase cuts with my mouse wheel.

Comment: forgot to switch to edit mode! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are now two ways to loop cut. The best is still to use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, using this method the scroll wheel will adjust the number of loop cuts.

If you are using the toolbar button to loop cut then the scroll wheel will adjust the zoom instead. You can increase the number of cuts using the menu.

[image]

You will also need to change the tool back to something else to get rid of the tool.
Long story short use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> not the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> [Loop Cut](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) shortcut doesn't work, it might be conflicting with a hotkey/shortcut from another piece of software running on your system. Try exiting other programs and then try the [Blender loop cut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pCf3DjsEBg) hotkey again. If problem still persists, you can always **assign a new shortcut to the Loop Cut tool**.

<kbd>RMB</kbd> on the loop cut tool icon in the tools panel, select <kbd>Assign Shortcut</kbd>, set it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this solution for myself, after the ones above did not work.

I went to the *Modeling Tab* at the top (which has displayed a lot of tools on the left side of the screen), then found the *Loop Cut*'s icon.

[image]

Right-clicked the *Loop Cut* icon and noticed no shortcut was assigned.

[image]

(If no shortcut is assigned, it should appear just as in the image below)

[image]

Click on *Assign a Shortcut* then press your desired shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem, and in order to solve this problem, I uninstalled uTorrent and all the VPN programs that were installed with it from my computer.
When I did that the problem was resolved and the shortcut was turned on in Blender again.

I don't know what uTorrent is doing to cause this problem, but I'm pretty sure it's using this shortcut for a reason.

In general, it is not a requirement that the cause of this problem is the uTorrent program, but it is possible that another program that you have installed on the device is the cause of this problem.

So, remember the programs you installed before this problem occurred and uninstall them completely and hopefully the problem will be resolved.